# HTML, CSS, PHP Portable Editor

Tags: html, php, css, programming, portable

I am looking for an HTML, CSS, PHP portable Editor, with FTP connection plugin, to connect my website using my flash memory drive, with all cache and connection data on it. To be correct, I want something like Notepad++ but portable version (please do not answer me like this "use Adobe DreamWeaver" because DreamWeaver is not an portable software officially).

Summing up:

- supports FTP to connect to the server
- supports HTML, CSS and PHP (syntax highlighting, if possible also code completion / function lookup)
- portable (possible to run it from USB stick wherever I am)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that "best" is not an objective criterion we can give recommendations upon. I took the freedom to [edit] and improve your question a bit. Not being a mind-reader, I couldn't fill all the gaps: do you need WYSIWYG features or at least a preview? Must the software be free, or what amount of money would you be willing to spend if needed? For a guide, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Note you always can [edit] your post to improve it :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CodeLobster portable](http://www.codelobster.com/) is a "Free portable IDE for PHP/HTML/CSS/JavaScript development". I used it for years anbd was very happy with it, before moving on to JetBrains products, which are not always free/portable.

It fulfills all of your requirements. Try it and tell us what you think.

```
PHP, HTML, JavaScript, CSS code highlighting
PHP, HTML, JavaScript, CSS code collapsing
HTML autocomplete
Autocomplete of tags, attributes for current tag, closing tags.
HTML/CSS code inspector
Inspector makes it simple to find HTML elements and their styles buried deep in the page.
HTML toolbar
CSS autocomplete
Autocomplete of style property names and values.
JavaScript Advanced autocomplete
Preview in a browser
```

> PHP Advanced autocomplete This feature speeds up writing a code.
>   Autocomplete includes wide selection of code completion listings.
>   Lists are formed of both standard PHP and user's classes, variables,
>   functions, constants and keywords. Starting typing new element, lists
>   of all possible variants for its completion are being displayed after
>   $this-> and ClassName:: PHP Debugger The Debugger is a package of
>   tools that allows a developer debug applications during developing
>   process. Before running, you need to configure it. Set necessary
>   values for the following options in Preferences menu
>   (Tools-->Preferences-->Debugger):
>
> ```
> Virtual folder - path to a virtual project folder
> Virtual host URL - url of a virtual folder
> Path to php.ini - path to the php.ini file
> Server - Apache version running on your computer. You need to select from the list, which displays all Apache versions installed on
> ```
>
> your machine.
>
> Features for debugger:
>
> ```
> Functions Step Into (F11), Step Over (F10), Stop Debug (Shift+F5)
> Watch window in debugger, only user's variables are displayed
> Local variables window and Call stack windows
> Expand of objects $this-> while debugging
> ```
>
> Context and Dynamic Help with search for work with PHP, MySQL, HTML
>   DynamicHelp window automatically lists all possible references for
>   current word. You also can use ContextHelp to get information about
>   shortcut keys. Portable option
>   Lite version also includes:
>
> ```
> FTP/SFTP support in the File Explorer, publishing for projects
> HTML, CSS, PHP code validator
> SQL manager
> Node.js (http://nodejs.org/)
> Support for Version Control Systems: SVN, Git etc.
> ```

And far too much more for me ot quote here. You really do need to read the web-site and download it. Please don't forget to tell us what you think of it.

Comment: CodeLobster is no longer portable!!!

Comment: @Eng Emad Can you please specify why Codelobster is not portable anymore and give a reference to that fact?

Comment: The [CoedLobster PHP fron page](https://www.codelobster.com/) says near the top that it is (still) portable

Answer (score 0):

The question has 4 years, but looks active.

I recommend to try [Kdevelop](https://www.kdevelop.org/).

Lightweight, fast and very complete IDE, with class completions and everything you might expect.

[image]